# Heroku push rejected with Phoenix 1.3

Tags: git, heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, package.json

I'm trying to do an initial commit with a phoenix v1.3 app but have the push rejected.  I've been following the Heroku specific deploy instructions on the Phoenix site here http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku. And I've used these to push other apps live before.

Looking at the console I'm suspecting it might be to do with `package.json`.  In phoenix 1.2 it was located under the root, but in 1.3 I can only find it at `myApp/Assets/package.json`.

*Console:*

```
Simons-MBP:dmt Simon$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 121, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
Writing objects: 100% (121/121), 55.47 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 121 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Phoenix app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Loading configuration and environment
remote:        Loading config...
remote:        WARNING: phoenix_static_buildpack.config wasn't found in the app
remote:        Using default config from Phoenix static buildpack
remote:        Detecting assets directory
remote:        WARNING: no package.json detected in root nor custom directory
remote:        * assuming phoenix 1.3.x and later, please check config file
remote:        Will use phoenix configuration:
remote:        * assets path assets
remote:        * mix tasks namespace phx
remote:        Will use the following versions:
remote:        * Node 6.9.2
remote:        Will export the following config vars:
remote: DATABASE_URL
remote: POOL_SIZE
remote: SECRET_KEY_BASE
remote:        * MIX_ENV=prod
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        Downloading node 6.9.2...
remote:        Installing Node 6.9.2...
remote:        Using default npm version
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing and caching node modules
remote: npm WARN package.json @ No description
remote: npm WARN package.json @ No README data
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/deps/phoenix
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/deps/phoenix_html
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.9.2
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/deps/phoenix
remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
remote:        npm ERR! syscall open
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/deps/phoenix'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/deps/phoenix'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
remote:        npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote:        npm ERR! enoent
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_511168ac1645065d539a7ada9e8efc0c/assets/npm-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Phoenix app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to digitalmoney.
```

*package.json:*

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "6.0.6",
    "brunch": "2.10.7",
    "clean-css-brunch": "2.10.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

*mix.exs*

```
defmodule Dmt.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :dmt,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.4",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases(),
     deps: deps()]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Dmt.Application, []},
     extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools]]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0-rc"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}


   ]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
  #
  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
     "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
     "test": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]]
  end
end
```

Comment: You only have one `package.json` in the app and it's in `/assets/package.json` right? I'm wondering how it even found it in that case and then decided to install the package relative to root. What happens if you change the path of the two dependencies and remove the `../` from each?

Comment: I wondered that myself.  Also worth nothing is that when I tried to install an npm css package, it didn't appear in that `package.json` file at all.  I'll try altering the path now.

Comment: removing `../` gives the same result `npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /deps/phoenix`